How do you change the resolution of a Windows guest running with libvirtd?
Trying to figure out a path to change the resolution on a Windows 11 guest running in libvirtd.
I found this gitlab site but the instructions tell you to inspect his code to then go on a manual hunt for various different files and organize them according to how he has his code setup and that seems overcomplex for what must be an extremely common procedure. It seems like you need the QXL driver, but I haven't found an obvious way to get that.
Is there a "straightforward" way to change the resolution of a Windows 11 guest in libvirtd?
